# Reactjs looping through array and switch

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a reactjs component and I am trying to render the data with a loop and switch.

I tried a map and then a forEach -- but it claims its not a function.

the json looks like this.

//json

```
"contents": {
          "0": ["emotional distress", "behavioural difficulties", "hyperactivity and concentration difficulties", "difficulties in getting along with other young people"],
          "5": ["kind and helpful behaviour"]
        }
```

//component

```
var YourCurrentStanding = React.createClass({

    alertLevel: function (key) {
      switch (key) {
        case '0': return "very high";
        case '1': return "high";
        case '5': return "very low";
        default: return "xy";
      } 
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log('this.props.data.contents', this.props.data.contents)
        return (
            <div>
                {
                  this.props.data.contents.forEach(function(j) {
                    return <p key={j}>Score for x,y and z {this.alertLevel(j)}</p>
                  })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

----------- should read like

```
"<p>Score for emotional distress, behavioural difficulties, hyperactivity and concentration difficulties very high and difficulties in getting along with other young people very high</p>

<p>Score for kind and helpful behaviour very low</p>"
```

---

near working code with a grammar check added

```
var YourCurrentStanding = React.createClass({

    grammarCheck : function(vals) {
      //x,y,z and d
      //z

      return vals.join(', ')
    },


    alertLevel: function(key) {
      switch (key) {
        case "0":
          return "very high";
        case "1":
          return "high";
        case "5":
          return "very low";
        default:
          return "xy";
      }
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(this.props.data.contents).map((key, index) => {      
            return <p key={index}>Score for {this.grammarCheck(this.props.data.contents[key])} is <b>{this.alertLevel(key)}</b></p>
        })}
      </div>
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: Use () => {} function syntax as your "this" isn't bind to your component but to your anonymous function. (i'm talking about your this.alertLevel)

Comment: where do I put that -- I tend to use var that = this -- then invoke that.alertLevel(j)

Comment: Contents is not an array it's an object. So it doesn't have the forEach method. You have to iterate through the object keys and then iterate through the array.

Comment: with the map method?

Comment: -- I can change the data structure -- just I felt that 0 - very high, - 1, high -- to use numbers in the key as opposed to words -- would be able to ensure the data is sorted correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: (Took sample **data** object for demo)

```js
var data = {
  contents: {
    "0": [
      "emotional distress",
      "behavioural difficulties",
      "hyperactivity and concentration difficulties",
      "difficulties in getting along with other young people"
    ],
    "5": ["kind and helpful behaviour"]
  }
};

var YourCurrentStanding = React.createClass({
  alertLevel: function(key) {
    switch (key) {
      case "0":
        return "very high";
      case "1":
        return "high";
      case "5":
        return "very low";
      default:
        return "xy";
    }
  },
  
  joinContents: function(data, key) {
    return [ data[key].slice(0, -1).join(", "), data[key].slice(-1)[0]         
           ].join(data[key].length < 2 ? "" : " and ");
     
    /*
     data[key].slice(0, -1).join(", "): takes all keys except last and joins them together with a comma.
     data[key].slice(-1)[0]: Last key
    */
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(data.contents).map((key, index) => {
          return (
            <p key={index}>
              Score for {this.joinContents(data.contents, key)} is {" "}
              <b>{this.alertLevel(key)}</b>
            </p>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<YourCurrentStanding />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: This is close -- how do you replace the xxx for the values -- "emotional distress, behavioural difficulties" - so like concat the array of values

Comment: need to add a comma - and remove a trailing comma

Comment: This should help you, now you should be able to relate and modify things

Comment: Its not entirely correct -- its producing individual sentences -- when they should be grouped.. eg... "<p>Score for emotional distress, behavioural difficulties, hyperactivity and concentration difficulties very high and difficulties in getting along with other young people very high</p>
<p>Score for kind and helpful behaviour very low</p>"

Comment: @TheOldCounty, ohh i didn't understood it clearly. Updated the snippet.

Comment: Its really close man -- but the 2nd to last item -- instead of a comma - needs to be an and..

Comment: __ I just added a grammacheck function --

Comment: -- this is the fix -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968091/javascript-comma-list-but-has-an-and-at-the-last-one/45968277#45968277

Answer (score 0):

Just use arrow function this way. And as @cesar william said, take care of maping on object properties.

```
render: function () {
    console.log('this.props.data.contents', this.props.data.contents)
    return (
        <div>
            {
              Object.keys(this.props.data.contents).map((key, index) => 
              {
                return <p key={index}>Score for xx {this.alertLevel(this.props.data.contents[j])}</p>
              })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

I didn't really look at your jsx paragraph but it's a good start.

Edit: you should never use index as key, find something that fits better, it was just for the example

Comment: -- what would be the better way to map the data? -- I used the numbers as a key to ensure its sorted by seriousness level first -- 0 - very high - 1 - high, 5 - very low

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate object by forEach or map methods.

```
const contentKeys = Object.keys(this.props.data.contents);
contentKeys.map(function(key, index) {
    const item = this.props.data.contents[index];
    return <p key={index}>Score for xx {this.alertLevel(item)}{index !== contentKeys.length-1 ? ', ' : null}</p>
});
```

Call alertLevel method with index or item – it's up to you.

Comment: --this churns out the contents, but there is no separating comma

Comment: Just added a grammar check function -- so maybe if(vals.length > 1){ vals.join(", ")   //replace last comma with an and } else { vals.join(",") }