# Javascript comma list but has an and at the last one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that will take a list of words -- and covert it into a sentence like this.

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/107/

// array list

```
"contents": {
   "0": ["emotional distress", "behavioural difficulties", "hyperactivity and concentration difficulties", "difficulties in getting along with other young people"],
   "5": ["kind and helpful behaviour"]
}
```

//sentence

```
"<p>Score for emotional distress, behavioural difficulties, hyperactivity and concentration difficulties very high and difficulties in getting along with other young people very high</p>
<p>Score for kind and helpful behaviour very low</p>"
```

//current function

```
grammarCheck : function(vals) {
  //x,y,z and d
  //z
  var count = vals.length;

  var text = vals.join(', ')

  //return [ this.props.data.contents[key].slice(0, -1).join(", "), this.props.data.contents[key].slice(-1)[0] ].join(this.props.data.contents[key].length < 2 ? "" : " and ");

  return text
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Well the error - is either just making a comma list -- or not placing the and at the correct section of the text.

Comment: //x,y,z, d  --- instead of //x,y,z and d

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/107/

Comment: -- what about using a regex to find and replace the last comma if there is an and?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```js
function createSentence(array) {
  if (array.length == 1) {
    return array[0];
  } else if (array.length == 0) {
    return "";
  }
  var leftSide = array.slice(0, array.length - 1).join(", ");
  return leftSide + " and " + array[array.length - 1];
}

console.log(createSentence(["dogs", "cats", "fish"]));
console.log(createSentence(["dogs", "cats"]));
console.log(createSentence(["dogs"]));
console.log(createSentence([]));
```

Comment: _ that will always produce a trailing and -- what if its just 1 word -- like in the last list

Comment: Also that does not rank the output based on the object keys

Comment: I'm more concerned about it always spewing out an "and" - even if its just got one word

Comment: Added a special case for 0 and 1 words

Comment: -- what about using a regex to find and replace the last comma if there is an and?

Comment: Honestly, that solution seems to be sort of brittle and I wouldn't recommend it. It essentially captures the same logic my answer (and some of the other answers) does while adding the complexity of a regex.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pop off the last item, and then join and place the last item within the sting

```js
function grammarCheck(vals) {
      //x,y,z and d
      //z
      var count = vals.length;

      var last = vals.pop()
      
      var text = vals.join(', ') + (vals.length > 1 ? ' and ' : '') + last

      return text
    }
    
    
    var arr = [
          ["emotional distress"],
          ["abc", "123", "blah", "blah", "blah"]
    ]
    
    arr.forEach(a => console.log('grammar check', grammarCheck(a)))
```

Comment: -- what about using a regex to find and replace the last comma if there is an and?

Answer (score 0):

The function you have commented out seems to be right, except that it's using some property off `this` rather than the parameter passed to it.

Adjusting that, you get this:

```
const grammarCheck = function(vals) {
  return [ vals.slice(0, -1).join(", "), vals.slice(-1)[0] ]
         .join(vals.length < 2 ? "" : " and ");
}
grammarCheck(['foo']); //=> 'foo'
grammarCheck(['foo', 'bar']); //=> 'foo and bar'
grammarCheck(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']); //=> 'foo, bar and baz'
grammarCheck(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']); //=> 'foo, bar, baz and qux'
```

Obviously, you could alter this a bit if you want the [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

Comment: -- what about using a regex to find and replace the last comma if there is an and?

Comment: @TheOldCounty: There are plenty of ways this could be done.  But this code is simply a tweak of the version in the question.  I don't know if there's anything wrong with it.  But, depending upon how it's implemented,  a regex solution might possibly fall victim in cases like `grammarCheck(['peas and carrots', 'pork and beans', 'pizza and beer'])`.  This solution shouldn't have such problems.