# Reactjs refactoring a word chart looping through json objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs component - which will band together a list of words in various alert status paragraphs.

This is what it will look like.

[image]

---

Its essentially a personality performance indicator -- but there are TWO bands of labels/alerts -- so band1 - red - is very high, but band2 - red - is very low.. so its like an inverse of state. So Overall Stress being red is very high and that's bad -- but for Kind and Helpful being red is very low is also bad.

My new json structure looks like this.

```
"contents": {
                "1": {
                  "1": {
                    "alert": "green",
                    "values": ["emotional distress", "hyperactivity and concentration"],
                    "label": "close to the average"
                  },
                  "2": {
                    "alert": "yellow",
                    "values": ["behavioural difficulties"],
                    "label": "slightly raised"
                  },
                  "4": {
                    "alert": "red",
                    "values": ["peer difficulties", "overall stress"],
                    "label": "very high"
                  }
                },
                "2": {
                  "4": {
                    "alert": "red",
                    "values": ["kind and helpful behaviour"],
                    "label": "very low"
                  }
                }
              }
```

My reactjs component looks like this. but its not rendering ALL the paragraph states for ALL the bands.

```
var YourCurrentStanding = React.createClass({

    createSentence : function(array) {
      if (array.length === 1) {
        return array[0];
      } else if (array.length === 0) {
        return "";
      }
      return array.slice(0, array.length - 1).join(", ") + " and " + array[array.length - 1];
    },

    /*
    alertLevel: function(key) {
      switch (key) {
        case "0":
          return 'very high';
        case "1":
          return 'high';
        case "2":
          return 'moderate';
        case "3":
          return 'low';
        case "4":
          return 'very low';
        default:
          return '';
      }
    },

    getAlertColor: function(key) {
      switch (key) {
        case "0":
          return 'rouge-text';
        case "1":
          return 'rouge-text';
        case "2":
          return 'amber-text';
        case "3":
          return 'light-yellow-text';
        case "4":
          return 'light-green-text';
        default:
          return '';
      }
    },*/

    _content: function(d) {
      //data -- sort by highest alert.
      //d.sort();

      //console.log("........d", d);      

      if(d){
        var size = Object.keys(d).length;
          const ordered = {};
          Object.keys(d).sort().forEach(function(key) {
            ordered[key] = d[key];
          });

          //ordered.reverse();
          console.log("........ordered", ordered);

          for (var key in ordered) {
            if (ordered.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              console.log(key + " -> " + ordered[key].alert);
              console.log(key + " -> " + ordered[key].values);
              console.log(key + " -> " + ordered[key].label);

              return (
                <p className="large-text margin-bottom">Score for {this.createSentence(ordered[key].values)} is <b className={ordered[key].alert+"-text"}>{ordered[key].label}</b></p>
              );

            }
          }
      }


      /*
      return (
        <p className="large-text margin-bottom" key={j}>Score for xxx is <b>vvv</b></p>
      );
      */

      /*
      d.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log(entry);
      });
      */

    },


    render: function() {
      var that = this;

      return (
        <div className="component-container">
          {
            Object.keys(this.props.data.contents).map((key, i) => {      

              console.log("key", key);
              console.log("index", i);

              //console.log("contents...", this.props.data.contents[i]);

              return (
                <div className="bands" key={i}>
                  {that._content(this.props.data.contents[i])}
                </div>
              )
              //return <p className="large-text margin-bottom" key={index}>Score for {this.createSentence(this.props.data.contents[key])} is <b className={this.getAlertColor(key)}>{this.alertLevel(key)}</b></p>
            })
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
});
```

---

current demo

```js
var data = {
  contents: {
    "1": {
              "1": {
                "alert": "green",
                "values": ["emotional distress", "hyperactivity and concentration"],
                "label": "close to the average"
              },
              "2": {
                "alert": "yellow",
                "values": ["behavioural difficulties"],
                "label": "slightly raised"
              },
              "4": {
                "alert": "red",
                "values": ["peer difficulties", "overall stress"],
                "label": "very high"
              }
            },
            "2": {
              "4": {
                "alert": "red",
                "values": ["kind and helpful behaviour"],
                "label": "very low"
              }
            }
  }
};


var YourCurrentStanding = React.createClass({

createSentence : function(array) {
  if (array.length === 1) {
    return array[0];
  } else if (array.length === 0) {
    return "";
  }
  return array.slice(0, array.length - 1).join(", ") + " and " + array[array.length - 1];
},

/*
alertLevel: function(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case "0":
      return 'very high';
    case "1":
      return 'high';
    case "2":
      return 'moderate';
    case "3":
      return 'low';
    case "4":
      return 'very low';
    default:
      return '';
  }
},

getAlertColor: function(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case "0":
      return 'rouge-text';
    case "1":
      return 'rouge-text';
    case "2":
      return 'amber-text';
    case "3":
      return 'light-yellow-text';
    case "4":
      return 'light-green-text';
    default:
      return '';
  }
},*/

_content: function(d) {
  //data -- sort by highest alert.
  //d.sort();

  //console.log("........d", d);      

  if(d){
    var size = Object.keys(d).length;
      const ordered = {};
      Object.keys(d).sort().forEach(function(key) {
        ordered[key] = d[key];
      });

      //ordered.reverse();
      console.log("........ordered", ordered);

      for (var key in ordered) {
        if (ordered.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(key + " -> " + ordered[key].alert);
          console.log(key + " -> " + ordered[key].values);
          console.log(key + " -> " + ordered[key].label);

          return (
            <p className="large-text margin-bottom">Score for {this.createSentence(ordered[key].values)} is <b className={ordered[key].alert+"-text"}>{ordered[key].label}</b></p>
          );

        }
      }
  }


  /*
  return (
    <p className="large-text margin-bottom" key={j}>Score for xxx is <b>vvv</b></p>
  );
  */

  /*
  d.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
  });
  */

},


render: function() {
  var that = this;




  return (
    <div className="component-container">
      {
        Object.keys(data.contents).map((key, i) => {      
      
          console.log("key", key);
          console.log("index", i);
          
          //console.log("contents...", this.props.data.contents[i]);

          return (
            <div className="bands" key={i}>
              {that._content(data.contents[key])}
            </div>
          )
          //return <p className="large-text margin-bottom" key={index}>Score for {this.createSentence(this.props.data.contents[key])} is <b className={this.getAlertColor(key)}>{this.alertLevel(key)}</b></p>
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(<YourCurrentStanding />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

---

this is an old thread - for the first instance of part of the problem.

[Reactjs looping through array and switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965005/reactjs-looping-through-array-and-switch)

[Javascript comma list but has an and at the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968091/javascript-comma-list-but-has-an-and-at-the-last-one)

Comment: just taking a quick look but shouldn't `return (
            <div className="bands" key={i}>
              {that._content(data.contents[i])}
            </div>
          )` be using `data.contents[key]` ??

Comment: "{that._content(this.props.data.contents[key])}" -- yes that's given access to the 2nd band -- now the inner list is not rendering --

Comment: Cheers @BenLonsdale the problem now appears to reside in "_content"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/170/ -- I've refactored the render - I can see the console logs - but when I try and return html - nothing gets rendered?

Comment: -- it was an issue with the forEach - had to replace it with map